# What is the significance of the coyote references in the Helter Skelter docuseries?

Tags: analysis, helter-skelter-2020

In a recent docuseries on Epix about Charles Manson called [*Helter Skelter*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12115298/) there are repeated references to a coyote image and video clips. They seem to be references to Manson himself and a sort of "spirit animal" reference or something. Below are a couple of examples. **Its obvious the creators are trying to use the image of the coyote in connection with Manson, but why? What does this symbol mean in this context and how does it apply to Manson?**

This image is from the opening credits in which a coyote is seen several times.
[image]

In one episode an image of a coyote is overlaid on an image of Manson. This is an example of the many images like this throughout the series.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because [Manson admired them](https://quotecatalog.com/quote/charles-manson-have-you-ever-s-O1MXQ4a/)?

> “Have you ever seen the coyote in the desert? Watching, tuned in, completely aware. Christ on the cross, the coyote in the desert — it’s the same thing, man. The coyote is beautiful. He moves through the desert delicately, aware of everything, looking around. He hears every sound, smells every smell, sees everything that moves. He’s in a state of total paranoia, and total paranoia is total awareness.”
>
> — Charles Manson, Charles Manson: The 1970 RS Interview

Also there is [this connection](https://www.cbsnews.com/pictures/terrifying-details-of-the-manson-murders/12/):

> Last meal
>
> On Aug. 8, 1969, Sharon Tate, Jay Sebring, Abigail Folger and Voytek Frykowski dine at **the L.A. landmark El Coyote**. The group leaves the restaurant around 10 p.m., and departs for 10050 Cielo Drive.